# Jquery plugin form no works

Tags: jquery, forms

I am using a plugin form from jquery to send a form but it isn't working

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxSubmit

My Script

```
<?php
$tfw_number_format="2";
?>


<script>
function send_forma(id)
{

jQuery('#contact-form-widget-'+id).ajaxForm(
{ 
dataType:  'json', 
success:   contact
});

}


function contac(data2)
{

if (data2.campos_vacios=="bad")
{
alert("ok");
}

}
</script>
```

---

```
<form id="contact-form-widget-<?php echo $tfw_number_format;?>" class="contact-form-widget" method="post" action="<?php echo $phpValidate;?>" onsubmit="send_forma('<?php echo $tfw_number_format;?>');return false;">

...... Fields and Submit 

</form>
```

I create this script to insert more forms in the same web page and no conflicts between, because if not, it doesn't work.

I hope you can help me in this

Thanks , Regards !!!

Comment: Your `success` callback function `contact` is spelled wrong. Your function is defined at `contac`. It seems like you also want data, I would write this as `success: function(data) { contac(data) }`

Comment: no work me , see this example please http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#json

Comment: still there is a typo (`conta`<> `contact`)

Answer (score 0):

This is not submitting the form:

```
jQuery('#contact-form-widget-'+id).ajaxForm(
{ 
dataType:  'json', 
success:   contact
});

}
```

It will turn it into an ajax form, but it won't submit it and therefore it is not a not suitable for submit handler
You have to make this call in the `$(document).ready(function() { }` block as it is in the sample.

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/balintbako/fxkH5/